# Modification set not working in cruise control

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Ant script to run clone

```
<target name="clone" description="get the latest files">
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <filesetdir="/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/Mss/copyExample/local_copy/Mss" defaultexcludes="false">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
    <exec executable="git" dir="/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/Mss/copyExample/local_copy/Mss">
        <arg line="clone -o fl ssh://git@ipaddress/git/run.git Mss" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

In my current CruiseControl setup I am running the following target:

```
<modificationsetquietperiod="60">
    <git localworkingcopy="${projects.dir}/${project.name}/local_copy/${project.name}/"/>
</modificationset>
```

Running cruisecontrol gives git exit with error code 1. I guess modificationset is not able to find git local working copy. 
Any help would be welcome and greatly appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `${project.name}` is `Mss`. However, you run `git` in `/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/Mss/copyExample/local_copy/Mss` and check out into folder `Mss`, creating folder `/opt/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/projects/Mss/copyExample/local_copy/Mss/Mss`.
Further, if your `${project.name}` does not expand to `Mss/copyExample`, you might have a problem, too.

In a nutshell, I think your paths is incorrect.